# Why are my tests passing with conflicting assertions?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am new to Python/Pytest and I'm trying to understand mocking/patching. I am currently adding tests to an existing codebase and am having a lot of trouble with these concepts.

I spent several hours reading through documentation (pytest, pytest-mock), Github issues, code, etc. I have also spent a lot of time experimenting trying to understand what I'm missing.

I have prepared a small sample project to help show what I'm seeing.

**Project structure:**

```
runner.py
mypkg
  __init__.py
  MyClass.py
  my_test.py
tests
  test_my_class.py
```

The contents of the files:

**runner.py:**

```py
from mypkg import my_test

my_test.run()
```

**mypkg/MyClass.py:**

```py
class MyClass:
    test_var = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.test_var = args[0]

    def do_something(self):
        self.do_something_else()

    def do_something_else(self):
        print('Something else')
        print(self.test_var)
```

**mypkg/my_test.py:**

```py
from .MyClass import MyClass

def run():
    x = MyClass('test')
    x.do_something()
```

**tests/test_my_class.py:**

```py
from mypkg import my_test

def test_my_test(mocker):
    mocker.patch('mypkg.my_test.MyClass')

    my_test.run()
    my_test.MyClass.assert_called_once_with('test')
    my_test.MyClass.assert_not_called
    assert my_test.MyClass.call_count == 1

    my_test.MyClass.return_value.do_something.assert_not_called
    assert my_test.MyClass.return_value.do_something.call_count == 1

    print(my_test.MyClass.mock_calls)
```

The problem is that the test is passing even with the conflicting assertions. I don't understand how the call_count can be 1 and the `assert_not_called` can pass at the same time. I'm not sure if I'm patching in the wrong place or doing something else incorrectly.

Dumping the mock calls to `my_test.MyClass` shows: `[call('test'), call().do_something()]`. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I am using python 3.6.5, pytest 4.4.1 and pytest-mock 1.10.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *method*. It should be called:

```
mock.assert_not_called    # does nothing useful 
mock.assert_not_called()  # actually makes an assertion
```